# John the Ripper and sparsebundle password help

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, encryption, sparsebundle

Around January 2014, my original hdd died on me, I bought a new hard drive and let the old one sit. Got myself an external enclosure recently, to recover my old work, only to realize my main folder had been encrypted with FileVault and i'd forgotten the password.

(It was encrypted on OS X 10.6, with legacy filevault)

I've seen John the Ripper mentioned a lot for cracking passwords, I've gotten as far as getting a build (1.7.9-jumbo-7 [macosx-x86-64]) installed. I have a word list ready and a vague idea of what my pass could be, I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I'm hoping I could get some guidance on what I would need to do next.

Edit: I'm running on os x 10.9, if this is relevant?

Comment: So you want us to help you to crack your Encryption password. Did it nor ask you for a password every time you booted up?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to open up myname.sparsebundle through the external drive, but whenever I attempt to open it, it wants me to enter my password, which I haven't used in a little over a year.

Comment: Any progress? Exactly the same thing here

Answer (score -1):

See this [official tutorial](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/README.Apple_DMG) for cracking encrypted Apple DMG files.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.